# APEX best practice

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am new to Salesforce apex coding. My first class that I am developing has 10 methods and is some 800 lines.

I haven’t added much of exception handling, so the size should swell further.

I am wondering, what the best practice for Apex code is... should I create 10 classes with 1 method instead of letting 1 class with 10 methods.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Argee

Answer (score 0):

What do you use for coding? Try to move away from Developer Console. VSCode has some decent plugins like Prettier or Apex PMD that should help you with formatting and making methods too complex. ~80 lines/method is so-so. I'd worry about passing long lists of parameters and having deeply nested code in functions rather than just their length.

There are general guidelines (from other languages, there's nothing special about Apex!) that ideally function should fit on 1 screen so programmer can see it whole without scrolling. Read this one, maybe it'll resonate with you: https://dzone.com/articles/rule-30-%E2%80%93-when-method-class-or

I wouldn't split it into separate files just for sake of it, unless you can clearly define some "[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)". Say 1 trigger per object, 1 trigger handler class (ideally derived from base class). Chunkier bits not in the handler but maybe in some "service" style class that has public static methods and can operate whether called from trigger, visualforce, lightning web component, maybe some one-off data fix would need these, maybe in future you'd need to expose part of it as REST service. And separate file for unit tests (as blasphemous as it sounds - try to not write too many comments. As you're learning you'll need comments to remind yourself what built-in methods do but naming your functions right can help a lot. And a well-written unit test is better at demonstrating the idea behind the code, sample usage and expected errors than comments that can be often overlooked).

Exception handling is an art. Sometimes it's good to just let it throw an exception. If you have a method that creates Account, Contact and Opportunity and say Opportunity fails on validation rule - what should happen? Only you will know what's good. Exception will mean the whole thing gets rolled back (no "widow" Accounts) which sucks but it's probably "more stable" state for your application. If you naively try-catch it without Database.rollback() - how will you tell user to not create duplicates with 2nd click. So maybe you don't need too much error handling ;)